# How can I get a user by email address using a service?

Tags: 7, services

I have a custom service that I created to do some stuff with users.  I want to be able to GET and DELETE users by email address because I may not know the uid.

I have the service set up now. It works through Postman, but through the actual client, it returns a 406 error because of the .com in the email.

How do I pass the email to the service if not through the URL?

This is the definition of the service.

```
'retrieve' => array(
    'help' => 'Retrieve a user',
    'file' => array(
        'type' => 'inc',
        'module' => 'user_service',
        'name' => 'user_service',
    ),
    'callback' => '_my_user_resource_retrieve',
    'access callback' => '_my_user_resource_access',
    'access arguments' => array('view'),
    'access arguments append' => true,
    'args' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'email',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => 'The email of the user to retrieve.',
            'source' => array('param' => 'email'),
            'optional' => false,
        ),
    ),
),
```

The callback function is the following.

```
function _my_user_resource_retrieve($mail) {
  return user_load_by_mail($mail);
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code example so that we can help you?

Comment: The code has a double return?

Comment: That was a typo on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Params are only for index functions. So you need to implement an index function, something like this from the `user_resources.inc` file in the Services module:

```
'index' => array(
    'help' => 'List all users',
    'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/user_resource'),
      'callback' => '_user_resource_index',
      'args' => array(
        array(
          'name' => 'page',
          'optional' => TRUE,
          'type' => 'int',
          'description' => 'The zero-based index of the page to get, defaults to 0.',
          'default value' => 0,
          'source' => array('param' => 'page'),
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'fields',
          'optional' => TRUE,
          'type' => 'string',
          'description' => 'The fields to get.',
          'default value' => '*',
          'source' => array('param' => 'fields'),
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'parameters',
          'optional' => TRUE,
          'type' => 'array',
          'description' => 'Parameters',
          'default value' => array(),
          'source' => array('param' => 'parameters'),
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'pagesize',
          'optional' => TRUE,
          'type' => 'int',
          'description' => 'Number of records to get per page.',
          'default value' => variable_get('services_user_index_page_size', 20),
          'source' => array('param' => 'pagesize'),
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'options',
          'optional' => TRUE,
          'type' => 'array',
          'description' => 'Additional query options.',
          'default value' => array(
            'orderby' => array(
              'created' => 'DESC'
            )
          ),
          'source' => array('param' => 'options'),
        ),
      ),
      'access arguments' => array('access user profiles'),
      'access arguments append' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
```